# RPI: Cannot install tensorflow==1.15

Tags: python, tensorflow, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

I have an issue with installing TensorFlow version 1.15. I have tried different python versions as well as virtual environments with no success. I have also tried installing the `whl` directly and following the TensorFlow set-up directions (am compatible with all requirements) but the system fails to recognize the existence of this version. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?
[showing need of TensorFlow v1.15](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eb5ng.png)
[showing lack of TensorFlow versions higher than 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zj4s4.png)

**rpi specifications:**

```
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

Comment: try: `sudo pip3 install tensorflow` ?

Comment: Otherwise, follow the steps in this link : https://qengineering.eu/install-tensorflow-1.15.2-on-raspberry-pi-4.html

Comment: https://www.bitsy.ai/3-ways-to-install-tensorflow-on-raspberry-pi/  among others

Answer (score 0):

That happened to me  when I tried it , the solution was to update the pip.
try :

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```